# Why can't this component access its props data?

Tags: vue.js

When the following component was inline, it was able to access `rowData` but as a referenced template it can't:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
      <row-component v-for="(row, index) in rows" :row-data="row" v-on:delete-row="deleteThisRow(index)"></row-component>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="theRow" type="x-template">
  row component: {{rowData}}
  <button @click="$emit('delete-row')">Delete3</button>
</script>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
Vue.component('row-component', {
    props: ["rowData"],
    template: '#theRow'
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        rows: ["line1", "line2", "line3", "line4", "line5"]
    },
    methods: {
        deleteThisRow: function(index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
})
```

How can I get the component to recognize `rowData`?

https://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/k1tx3z1n/

Comment: I ran your jsfiddle, and it is recognizing your `rowData`. The only change I did was, to add a `<div>` as the root inside the `<script>` template. That is because vue needs a **single** root element.

Answer (score 0):

Components should have only [one root element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Fragment-Instances-removed)

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
      <row-component v-for="(row, index) in rows" :row-data="row" v-on:delete-row="deleteThisRow(index)"></row-component>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="theRow" type="x-template">
    <div>
          row component: {{rowData}}
          <button @click="$emit('delete-row')">Delete3</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

See the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1tx3z1n/1/)